# Chromecast giving error code 7 when trying to connect

Tags: android, chromecast

Where can I find the error codes for Chromecast?

Since Friday, I was able to connect to and stream to my Chromecast but over the weekend something must have changed with Chromecast because now I am getting error code 7.

What does this mean? I have tried to find a full listing of possible error codes for Chromecast and have been unsuccessful.

I have not changed my code over the weekend or anything and now I am having trouble connecting to any devices, and looking for something more descriptive to understand why other than error code 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sender platform is this? In Android, that error may mean [network](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes.html#NETWORK_ERROR) issue.

Comment: Android platform. Okay i thought this may be because my network has not been very reliable. Is there a reference for error codes for chromecast. This error is not happening right now.

Comment: The link I mentioned is the reference, that class has various constants including errors.